# Shortcut method to setting form values in jQuery

Tags: jquery

Is there a neater way to set form values from data returned from the server rather than doing like below?

```
$('#form' input[name=x]').val(data['x']);
$('#form' input[name=y]').val(data['y']);
$('#form' input[name=z]').val(data['z']);
$('#form' input[name=a]').val(data['a']);
$('#form' input[name=b]').val(data['b']);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the names of the input and the attributes returned in the `data` are identical, you could do something like this (assuming your data is returned as an object):

```
$.each(data, function(key, val) {
    $('#form input[name=' + key + ']').val(val);
});
```